# Доступ к домену по всем поддоменам (субдоменнам)

Tags: linux, apache, nginx, веб-сервер

Необходимо, чтобы по любому несуществующему поддомену был доступен домен. Я понимаю, что нужно настроить DNS, чтобы он отправлял все запросы на домен, а в настройках Apache указать алиас на типа *.домен.ру, к примеру. Но тоже не знаю как это грамотно сделать.

Подскажите, как такое реализовать.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш вопрос слишком общий, поэтому на него трудно дать объективный ответ. Укажу общее направление.

Задача делится на две части.

Во-первых, вам нужно сделать так, чтобы при обращении к DNS на любой поддомен выдавался некоторый IP-адрес (поведение по умолчанию -- нет записи в DNS -- ответ так и будет "не найдено").

Эта часть вопроса очень обширная... Во-первых, с большой степенью вероятности вы не держите зону самостоятельно (две географически независимые подсети класса С, собственные DNS-сервера и т.п.), а ведёт ваш регистратор домена. Все они как правило совмещают несколько услуг: где регистрировали домен - там и панелька для добавления/правки записей в DNS. И во-вторых, с большой степенью вероятности ваш провайдер не может сделать так, чтобы на несуществующие записи выдавался какой-то дефолтный IP.

Что можно сделать?

Первый вариант - подымать DNS-сервер и настраивать его как душе угодно. Подробностей не даю, так как это вам сами -- выбираете тип сервера (На винде или на линуксе), настраивайте. Будут конкретные вопросы -- задавайте отдельно.

Второй вариант -- поискать провайдера, который предоставит вам такую услугу. Я из таких провайдеров навскидку могу назвать только network solution. Не знаю, насколько пример будет актуальным через год/два/три -- так что это тоже вам самим искать.

Вторая часть вопроса относится к настройке веб-сервера и она независима от настройки DNS. Почему независима? Потому что вы всегда можете в файл hosts вписать пару несуществующих поддоменов и сэмулировать настроенный bind или что там у вас будет в качестве DNS.

Так вот как это решается, если у вас сервер на базе apache: при настроенных виртуал хостс один из них будет являться хостом по умолчанию, на него и пойдёт весь трафик с нераспознанных запросов.

Плюс можно явно прописать, как в [этом вопросе на en so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13566226/5752652).

А для сервера на базе Nginx всё делается через * в servername:

```
server_name  mydomain.tld *.mydomain.tld;
```

Либо через дефолтный виртуальный хост:

```
listen 80 default_server;
```

(Для обработки https вам нужно иметь wildcard-сертификат, его цена обычно на порядок выше, чем обычный сертфикат -- а letsencrypt кажется, до сих пор не выдаёт бесплатные wildcard)

Как-то так в общих словах.

Update. Дополнение к ответу на уточняющий вопрос.

> Я хочу что бы у меня сайт был доступен по всем под-доменам 3-его
>   уровня и название под-домена 3 уровня ложилось в переменную сервера
>   например, запускается все это дело на виртуальной машине битрикса так
>   что настроит все как нужно не проблема. Хотелось бы знать реально ли
>   это реализовать вообще ?

Конечно реально. В PHP есть глобальная переменная $_SERVER и вы всегда можете узнать имя хоста в наборе данных. Оно передаётся веб-сервером, вы можете брать HTTP_HOST и парсить его, выделяя имя поддомена, если оно вам нужно.

Comment: "с большой степенью вероятности ваш провайдер не может сделать так, чтобы на несуществующие записи выдавался какой-то дефолтный IP." - а можно пример такого? Я работал с доменами у трёх разных регистраторов - все могли

Comment: Алсо, у Let's Encrypt wildcard скоро будет

Comment: @andreymal На nic.ru включите DNS-мастер и попробуйте сделать. На мастерхост попробуйте сделать. Это навскидку. А сертификаты от le давно жду.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Я хочу что бы у меня сайт был доступен по всем под-доменам 3-его уровня и название под-домена 3 уровня ложилось в переменную сервера например, запускается все это дело на виртуальной машине битрикса так что настроит все как нужно не проблема. Хотелось бы знать реально ли это реализовать вообще ?

Comment: @ИгорьБраницкий Вы знаете, мне удивительно почему вы сразу это уточнение не написали в своём вопросе, а уже тогда когда вам дан общий ответ и теперь вам надо по факту задавать новый вопрос. Вы не видите, сколько вопросов в день закрывается и минусуется за плохие формулировки, за слишком общие расплывчатые вопросы и сколько людей с сайта уходит в негативе, чтобы никогда не вернуться?